# CODE 127 and Selenium version not found while using selenium on replit (linux)

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, replit

MY code :

```
service = webdriver.ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()) # Change the path as needed
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    # Open the HTML file
    driver.get("file://" + html_file_path)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    xpath="/html/body/div/div[1]"
    elembyxp=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
    elembyxp.screenshot(f"{image_file_path}")
    driver.quit()
```

ERROR:

```
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/runner/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

i have already added pkgs.chromium and pkgs.chromedriver in the nix file

and if i do not put the version as 114 it gives this error

```
There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/117.0.5938.88/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

I have not included binary in local path as in new selenium version selenium manager Does this by itself , there is no way to add executable path too

STEPS TO REPRODUCE -

1. Go to replit
2. make a new python repl
3. try to Run any basic
   selenium code that has element screenshot function